# Can't run any Python script on my Android phone

Tags: scripts

I have an Acer Liquid Metal, Gingerbread...

I've tried installing Python on Android (and s4la: http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) but when I run the hello world script I get:

`dlopen libpython2.6.so`

`Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File "compass.py", line 2, in <module>`

`droid = android.Android()`

`File "/sdcard/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/extras/python/android.py", line`
`34, in __init__`

`self.conn = socket.create_connection(addr)`

`File "/home/manuel/AptanaStudio3Workspace/python-for-android/python-build/output/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 498, in create_connection
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] hostname nor servname provided, or not known."`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy peasy:

I was using adaway (an app that blocks ads) and somehow its tweaking of my hosts file was not accepted by Python.

Yay! :D